# comparing version return too long or too short exception

Tags: c#, version

This is how I compare *version*

```
var _vA = new Version("0.9.9.1.1");
var _vB = new Version("0.9.9.1.2");

return (_vA.CompareTo(_vB) <= 0);
```

It **throws exception**:

> Version string portion was too short or too long.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both versions are guaranteed to be in format

```
A.B.C ... .X.Y.Z
```

where all version's parts (`A`, `B`, ..., `Z`) can contain *digits* `0..9` only (which we can check with a help of *regular expressions* - `bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(version, @"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$");`), we can compare them as

```
private static string[] VersionToArray(string version) {
  string[] result = version
    .Split('.')
    .Select(item => item.TrimStart('0'))
    .ToArray();

  // If we want to remove trailing zeros, i.e. 1.0.0.0.0.0 == 1.0.0.0 == 1.0:
  result = result
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(item => item.All(c => c == '0'))
    .Reverse()
    .ToArray();

  return result;
}

private static int CompareVersions(string left, string right) {
  string[] leftArray = VersionToArray(left);
  string[] rightArray = VersionToArray(right);

  for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(leftArray.Length, rightArray.Length); ++i) {
    int result = leftArray[i].Length.CompareTo(rightArray[i].Length);

    if (result == 0)
      result = string.Compare(leftArray[i], rightArray[i]);

    if (result != 0)
      return result;
  }

  return leftArray.Length.CompareTo(rightArray.Length);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Tuple<string, string>[] tests = new Tuple<string, string>[] {
  Tuple.Create("0.9.9.1.2", "0.9.9.1.1"),
  Tuple.Create("0.9.9.1.1", "0.9.9.1.2"),
  Tuple.Create("0.9.9.1.1", "0.9.9.1.1"),
  Tuple.Create("0", "1"),
  Tuple.Create("0", "0.0.0.0"),
  Tuple.Create("0.0.1.0", "0.0.0.1"),
  Tuple.Create("1.0", "1.0.0"),
  Tuple.Create("1.10", "1.1"),
  Tuple.Create("1.1", "1.01"),
  Tuple.Create("10.0", "9.0"),
  Tuple.Create("012345678901234567890.1", "012345678901234567890.1"),
};

string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => new {
     v1 = test.Item1,
     v2 = test.Item2,
     comp = CompareVersions(test.Item1, test.Item2)
   })
   .Select(rec => 
      $"{rec.v1,25} {(rec.comp == 0 ? "=" : rec.comp < 0 ? "<" : ">")} {rec.v2}"));

Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
                0.9.9.1.2 > 0.9.9.1.1
                0.9.9.1.1 < 0.9.9.1.2
                0.9.9.1.1 = 0.9.9.1.1
                        0 < 1
                        0 = 0.0.0.0
                  0.0.1.0 > 0.0.0.1
                      1.0 = 1.0.0
                     1.10 > 1.1
                      1.1 = 1.01
                     10.0 > 9.0
  012345678901234567890.1 = 012345678901234567890.1
```

**Edit:** In case we want to return `bool` if `source >= target` (i.e. `source` is *at least* `target`), see comments below, we can put

```
  string source = "1.2.3.0.4.5.7";  // actual version
  string target = "1.2.3.0.3.9.75"; // minimum accepted version

  if (CompareVersions(source, target) >= 0) {
    // source is at least target, i.e. source >= target
  }
```

Comment: Let say the `left` is target and `right` is a source.
I only want to retrun `Boolean` value that can tell the source is latest or not by comparing the target .

Comment: @Steven Sann: `if (CompareVersions(source, target) >= 0) {/* source >= target */}`, please, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The Version allows typically 2 to 4 components. In your example, you have more components. To solve this issue, you would need to remove components of Version. For example,

```
0.9.9.1
0.9.9.2
```

You can read more on Version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Typical Version Components are

> Major: Assemblies with the same name but different major versions are
>   not interchangeable. A higher version number might indicate a major
>   rewrite of a product where backward compatibility cannot be assumed.
>
> Minor: If the name and major version number on two assemblies are the
>   same, but the minor version number is different, this indicates
>   significant enhancement with the intention of backward compatibility.
>   This higher minor version number might indicate a point release of a
>   product or a fully backward-compatible new version of a product.
>
> Build: A difference in build number represents a recompilation of the
>   same source. Different build numbers might be used when the processor,
>   platform, or compiler changes.
>
> Revision: Assemblies with the same name, major, and minor version
>   numbers but different revisions are intended to be fully
>   interchangeable. A higher revision number might be used in a build
>   that fixes a security hole in a previously released assembly.

Comment: is there any method to compare such a long version string ? ( with 5 digit )